# Why is this part of my script code being ignored?

Tags: javascript

I get no errors in the console, and the rest of the script works, but this part is just ignored and skipped. I have everything defined, but its like there is no data in the waypoints var, even though they are typed in by the user.All I get is the output of start and end but not the waypoints in the middle. [Fiddle of the entire code](https://jsfiddle.net/hughesb6/z9h3aq6b/)

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
}

var waypoints1 = ("");
var waypoints2 = ("");
var waypoints3 = ("");
var waypoints4 = ("");

var wayArray = [(waypoints1), (waypoints2), (waypoints3), (waypoints4)];
var wayArray = 'waypoints'

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var waypoints = [wayArray];
    //var waypts = [];

    var wayArray = document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints');

    for (var i = 0; i < wayArray.length; i++) {

      if (wayArray[i].value) {
        wayArray.push({
          location: wayArray[i].value,
          stopover: true
        });
      }
    }

    directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          waypoints: wayArray,
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
```

Comment: Note: `wayArray` can't hold an array (`= [(waypoints1), ...]`), a string (`= 'waypoints'`), and a collection of Elements (`= document.getElements...`) all at once. Try giving each of those uses their own distinct variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse `wayArray` by overwriting not by adding at the end. So delete/comment out the global variables in lines 18-24 (inclusive) in your Fiddle and replace the inner loop with

```
for (var i = 0; i < wayArray.length; i++) {
  if (wayArray[i].value) {
    wayArray[i] = {
      location: wayArray[i].value,
      stopover: true
    };
  }
}
```

Mmh...it makes me wonder why the first version of the loop stopped at all: the `wayArray.push()` makes the array bigger and hence `i < wayArray.length` is always true. Ah, the class name `waypoints` doesn't exist, only `waypoints[1-4]`—you should correct that, too.

EDIT: I'm to soft for stackoverflow, so here's a working example, tested with the route:

From: Minneapolis, MN;
Over: Madison, WI; Rockford, IL; Indianapolis, IN; Columbus, OH
To: Pittsburgh, PA

Works on latest Firefox/Linux

Output was:

```
Route Segment: 1
Minneapolis, MN, USA to Madison, WI, USA
268 mi

Route Segment: 2
Madison, WI, USA to Rockford, IL, USA
73.2 mi

Route Segment: 3
Rockford, IL, USA to Indianapolis, IN, USA
272 mi

Route Segment: 4
Indianapolis, IN, USA to Columbus, OH, USA
175 mi

Route Segment: 5
Columbus, OH, USA to Pittsburgh, PA, USA
185 mi
```

Checked by eyeballing, seems to be in the ballpark.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Waypoints</title>
<style type="text/css">
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}
#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

#right-panel {
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#directions-panel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #FFEE77;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqkH9U10wjgseSMBV07LmZETO5VQOT1Lw&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  // changed classnames!
  var wayArray = document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints');
  var wp = [];
  // overwriting did not work, tokk extra array instead
  for (var i = 0; i < wayArray.length; i++) {
    if (wayArray[i].value) {
      var tmp = wayArray[i].value;
      wp[i] = {
        location: tmp,
        stopover: true
      };
    }
  }
console.log(JSON.stringify(wp));
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    waypoints: wp,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
          '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="right-panel">
    <div>
      <b>Start:</b>
      <br>
      <input id="start" type="text" value="">
      <br>
      <b>Waypoints:</b>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="waypoints" value="">
      <input type="text" class="waypoints" value="">
      <input type="text" class="waypoints" value="">
      <input type="text" class="waypoints" value="">
      <br>
      <b>End:</b>
      </br>
      <input id="end" type="text" value="">
      <br>
      <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel"></div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      initMap();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to create a new class name that includes waypoints 1-4? i have been looking online but haven;t found any way to as of yet.

Comment: I commented out the lines you mentioned and replaced the inner loop. I also  added the class name waypoints and changed the getElementsByClassName to this :                                                            var wayArray = document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints waypoints1 waypoints2 waypoints3');  but it still ignores the waypoints code

Comment: Do you have any additional thoughts?

Comment: Did you check that the wayArray has the correct data, or is it already wrong there? What are your exact data, that is: start, end, the four waypoints to enable others to repeat it? Are all reachable by car? (As far as I remember Google ignores them if `travelMode` is set to `google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING` but that might have changed) BTW: it must be `document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints1 waypoints2 waypoints3 waypoints4');`

Comment: latest updated fiddle  [link]( https://jsfiddle.net/hughesb6/z9h3aq6b/)  travel mode driving is accepted now. exact data is "start" "waypoints" "end"

Comment: Fiddle `z9h3aq6b` is not different from original one, wrong link, forgot to update? (I'm not very familiar with using Fiddle, so bear with me). And if you are at it: please clean it up and make it runnable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hughesb6/z9h3aq6b/6/    here is the correct one. I clicked update this time.

Comment: I am going to dig into this so I can understand it. it works great!!!!!!!! TY!!!!!